# Trying to click on a hyperlink for a row with specific value in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium, There are 2 things I need to do
1. To take a note of the file name on the html but its part of a string so dont know how to concatenate it in Selenium IDE
2. In a table, after searching for the relevant file, I would like to click on a link in one of the other columns for that row. So For the file EMED.pdf, I would like to click the Requested link

HTML snippet:

```
<td>
<a class="OSfileLink" target="selenium_blank7934" href="/Practice/DownloadFile/8057329d-21df-4a44-baee-2068fc01b7dd" rel="EMED.pdf" style="background-color: transparent;">EMED.pdf</a>
</td>
<td></td>
<td> 27/02/2013 16:19:16 </td>
<td>
<a class="eApproval " data-toggle="modal" data-fileid="8057329d-21df-4a44-baee-2068fc01b7dd" href="#" rel="Requested (28/02/2013)" style="background-color: transparent;">Requested (28/02/2013)</a>
</td>
```

So far I have :

Command: click
Target:  //a[contains(text(),'Requested ')]/following-sibling::a[contains(text(),'EMED.pdf')]
value :

This brings up an error:
[error] Element //a[contains(text(),'Requested ')]/following-sibling::a[contains(text(),'EMED.pdf')] not found

I can "Find" the individual xpath's seperately, but they dont work together. Any help will be appreciated.

- Edit
  Still no joy with the concatenation, but can work round it with the click being identified. 
  Any help with concatenation will be much apprciated

***** EDIT
Concatenation: For:  href="/Practice/DownloadFile/8057329d-21df-4a44-baee-2068fc01b7dd"
I'd like the guid: 8057329d-21df-4a44-baee-2068fc01b7dd from the whole link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have your order swapped, try replacing `following-sibling` with `preceding-sibling`. Also note you want the `<a>` nodes, but the following-sibling function is checking the next node after `<a>`, which is `<td>`, so you'll need to start with the `<td>` nodes and check the content of each `<a>` node within.

Or the other way around, you could change which node you're starting your search with. If you want the "EMED.pdf" but only if the next node is "Requested", try something like this:

`//td[contains(a/text(),'EMED.pdf')]/following-sibling::td[contains(a/text(),'Requested')]/a`

Comment: Thanks JWiley, that worked too. What I didnt do was to contain the a in the td..and with your explanation it all now makes loads of sense.

Comment: @user2119891 Could you elaborate on what you mean by needing help with the concatenation? I'll add it to my answer if so

Comment: Hi JWiley, I've updated what I would like. I can store it as a sctring, but then how would I extract the guid from it?

Comment: Ah, ok so you only want that part of the text... I'll update my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

based on the html you put up, I think this works, I tested it with firefox xpath tester

> //.[td[a[contains(text(),'EMED.pdf')]]]//a[contains(text(),'Requested')]